# Total sum difference of multiple colums MYSQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am needing help trying to order a table by total absolute difference of individual columns. Ordered from lowest total difference to highest.

For example I will take User1, and compare all of it's "an" columns to all other Users and individually take the total difference of each column, adding to a running total of difference, and displaying all other users sorted by that amount, lowest to highest.

The difference of User1 an1 and User2 an1 would be 0, then would be 1 for an2, and 2 for an3. So the total difference would be 3.

```
| User|  an1  |  an2  | an3 |
----------------------------
| 1   |   1   |   4   |  3  |
| 2   |   1   |   5   |  5  |
| 3   |   2   |   3   |  4  |
| 4   |   2   |   4   |  1  |
```

Comment: I assume you have code that deals with this. Could you add it?

Comment: Something like sum(abs(an1 - an2)) as an2diff should work to get the  difference between an1 and an2

Comment: In a well designed schema, there would be only one an column

Comment: See for instance http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7660ab/1

Comment: Or http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7660ab/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query that has a self join, like this:

```
select a.User User1, 
       b.User User2, 
       abs(a.an1 - b.an1) + abs(a.an2 - b.an2) + abs(a.an3 - b.an3) scorediff
from   tbl as a
inner join tbl as b on a.User < b.User
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: This was fantastic and exactly what I needed, thank you. The issue I'm running into now is that I'm using sequelize with my current project and can't figure out a way to migrate this syntax over to sequelize. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: In that case you should ask a new question, so that SO members with expertise in sequelize can give the most appropriate way to do that. Make sure to tag it with sequelize.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will do that. I found another way to possibly make it work. I would need to join that response table to a user information table that I have to pull identifying information for the users.